# BNF grammar definition for Solidity

Tags: solidity, parser, grammar

I scoured the Mix and Solidity repos for something like a formal definition of the language's grammar, so that one may generate parsers using tools like [GrammarKit](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit), but couldn't find anything.

Any pointers?

Comment: If there's no answer here, I suggest trying https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a file called grammar.txt in the Solidity repo:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/grammar.txt

That's probably what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks! I searched for "grammar" in the same repo, and the only thing GitHub was able to find was "Scanner.cpp"... Too bad they're not using BNF, I might raise an issue for that. Should be easy to convert though.

Comment: @Matthias could you explain how to convert that file to BNF?

Comment: NOTE: This has now moved to https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/grammar.txt

Comment: the 2nd link is also broken, but here’s a “mirror”: https://ethereumacademy.blogspot.com/2017/10/describing-syntax-of-solidity-using-bnf.html?m=1

Answer (score 8):

I wrote an ANTLR4 grammar for Solidity that you may find useful:

https://github.com/solidityj/solidity-antlr4

It can generate parsers in any of the ANTLR [supported targets](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/targets.md) and it has full support for the Solidity language as of today.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another link pointing to the solidity documentation:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#language-grammar

Answer (score 1):

There is also a xText grammar, https://github.com/webdaford/smart-contract-tools/blob/master/workspace/com.dell.research.bc.eth.solidity.editor/src/com/dell/research/bc/eth/solidity/editor/Solidity.xtext which is quite similar to BNF.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [grammar based on javascript grammar](https://github.com/ConsenSys/solidity-parser/blob/master/solidity.pegjs).