# EVM grammar in ANTLR or something similar?

Tags: solidity, evm, grammar

Where can I find a machine readable grammar for EVM? (and for Solidity)

Also, apart from Solidity, what other high-level languages currently exist that compile to EVM opcodes?

The reason I am asking is I'm looking for (or trying to create) some static analysis tools that look at EVM or Solidity and find exploits like TheDAO.

Answer (score 3):

The question of grammar - specifically for Solidity - has come up before:

- [BNF grammar definition for Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/bnf-grammar-definition-for-solidity)

...as has the question of what languages are available for writing smart contracts:

- [What are the contract languages?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-are-the-contract-languages/368#368)

In addition to the languages mentioned in the previous (rather old) answer, there is also an experimental language based on Python called [Viper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10096/52).

Finally, I believe static analysis is something that the Browser Solidity folks have been looking at (see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/issues/252)), which together with the EVM enhancements outlined in issue [#3404](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/issues/3404) will supposedly make code more easily statically analysed.

**Edit:**

Solidity's `grammar.txt` file has moved since the linked answer was posted. It can now be found here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/grammar.txt

Comment: I saw the linked question on BNF grammar. Unfortunately, the links are all dead, so that answer is no longer useful.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Solidity's `grammar.txt` can  be found here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/grammar.txt

Comment: This looks very similar to ANTLR. What language is this in?

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [xText project](https://github.com/webdaford/smart-contract-tools) and the xText gramma description is quite similar to BNF:

> [Solidity.xtext](https://github.com/webdaford/smart-contract-tools/blob/b9381fe997a5b1cbc8e6bc43e00ef032edd7f712/workspace/com.dell.research.bc.eth.solidity.editor/src/com/dell/research/bc/eth/solidity/editor/Solidity.xtext)

xText uses ANTLR in the background.